# Can dart script call GWT's RemoteServiceServlet

Tags: gwt, dart

I have a Dart project want to reuse the existing GWT service (RemoteServiceServlet), any way can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special support for GWT-RPC included in Dart and there seem to be no 3rd-Party apps available that provide this functionality.

This question is similar (but not Dart)

[GWT Data Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782495)

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling ambitious, you can write a Dart client that understand the [GWT-RPC wire-protocol](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit?pli=1) and use that to communicate. This is likely to be a great deal of work however.

I had a similar situation where I needed to access GWT-RPC Services from a non-GWT client (it was JavaScript, not Dart, but the same concept applies). Instead of accessing the GWT-RPC service directly, I ended up using [jsonrpc4j](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j) to setup a JSON-RPC service alongside GWT-RPC. I was able to point jsonrpc4j at the GWT services to use, so there was no code duplication, just the extra code needed to wire up the JSON-RPC.

Then you will need a Dart JSON-RPC client, of which there are a few available: [jsonrpc](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_rpc), [jsonrpc2](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jsonrpc2).

This all assumes that you have access to the GWT server and can setup the JSON-RPC service.